# How to extend KineticJS shape

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

For KineticJS version **4.0.0** or less a shape extended a class and could be extended by

```
var MyCircle = Kinetic.Circle.extend({
    init : function(config) {
        this._super(config));
    },
    myFunc : function(){}
});
```

Or

```
Kinetic.MyCircle = function (config) {
    Kinetic.Circle.apply(this, [config]);
};
Kinetic.MyCircle .prototype = {
    myFunc: function () {}
};
Kinetic.GlobalObject.extend(Kinetic.MyCircle , Kinetic.Circle);
```

In version **4.0.1** they removed the dependencies to the class utility and implemented a custom solution that is supposed to be much faster.

How does one extend a shape with the new solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kinetic.GlobalObject became Kinetic.Global (>4.0.1), then
Kinetic.Global is now **Kinetic.Util** (2013 versions), here is a solution:

```
(function() {
    Kinetic.MyCircle = function(config) {
        this._initMyCircle(config);
    };

    Kinetic.MyCircle.prototype = {
        _initMyCircle: function(config) {
            Kinetic.Circle.call(this, config);
            },
        myFunc : function(){
        }
    };

  Kinetic.Util.extend(Kinetic.MyCircle, Kinetic.Circle);
})();
```

Comment: I think it is   Kinetic.Util.extend(Kinetic.MyCircle, Kinetic.Circle); nowadays (see for instance the circle object at http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.4.js)

Comment: Is there a standard naming convention to use instead of _initMyCircle? It seems redundant because it's obviously the MyCircle initializer, but calling it _init causes errors