# Select multiple custom objects on KineticJS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

Good Evening for everyone. I create a object on KineticJS that has this methods:

```
 function addCelestial(cb){
this.celestialBody = new Kinetic.Circle({
    id: cb.id,
    x:cb.x,
    y:cb.y,
    fill:cb.color,
    radius:cb.radius,
    shadowColor: cb.glow,
    shadowBlur: cb.glowBlur,
    shadowOffset: 0,
    shadowOpacity: cb.glowOpacity
});
this.xpos = function(value){
    if (typeof value === "undefined") {
        return this.celestialBody.getX();
    } else {
        this.celestialBody.setX(value);
    }
};
this.ypos = function(value){
    if (typeof value === "undefined") {
        return this.celestialBody.getY();
    } else {
        this.celestialBody.setY(value);
    }
};
this.xvel = function(value){
    if (typeof value === "undefined") {
        return this.xvel_v;
    } else {
        this.xvel_v = value;
    }
};
this.yvel = function(value){
    if (typeof value === "undefined") {
        return this.yvel_v;
    } else {
        this.yvel_v = value;
    }
};
this.xacc = function(value){
    if (typeof value === "undefined") {
        return this.xacc_v;
    } else {
        this.xacc_v = value;
    }
};
this.yacc = function(value){
    if (typeof value === "undefined") {
        return this.yacc_v;
    } else {
        this.yacc_v = value;
    }
};
this.mass = function(value){
    if (typeof value === "undefined") {
        return this.mass_v;
    } else {
        this.mass_v = value;
    }
};
this.radius = function(value){
    if (typeof value === "undefined") {
        return this.celestialBody.getRadius();
    } else {
        this.celestialBody.setRadius(value);
    }
};
this.resetForce = function(){
    this.xacc(0);
    this.yacc(0);       
};
this.calcNewState = function(){
    this.xvel(this.xvel() + this.xacc() * timestep);
    this.yvel(this.yvel() + this.yacc() * timestep);
    this.xpos(this.xpos() + timestep + this.xvel());
    this.ypos(this.ypos() + timestep + this.yvel());
};
this.addForce = function(otherbody){
    var radius = Math.pow(Math.pow(otherbody.ypos()-this.ypos(),2)+Math.pow(otherbody.xpos()-this.xpos(),2),0.5);
    var Gacc = otherbody.mass()/(Math.pow(radius,2));
    var angle = Math.atan2((otherbody.ypos()-this.ypos()),(otherbody.xpos()-this.xpos()));
    this.xacc(this.xacc()+Gacc*Math.cos(angle));
    this.yacc(this.yacc()+Gacc*Math.sin(angle));
};
this.logStatus = function(name){
    console.log(name+' xpos:'+this.xpos()+' ypos'+this.ypos()+' xacc:'+this.xacc()+' yacc:'+this.yacc()+' xvel:'+this.xvel()+' yvel:'+this.yvel());
};
this.getChildren = function(){
    return this;
};

cb.layer.add(this.celestialBody);
```

}

Then, i create a loop to create this objects:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20;i++){

        var asteroidID = 'asteroid' + i;

        var asteroid = new addCelestial({color: 'rgb(255,255,255)',layer:layer0, id: asteroidID});
        asteroid.radius(1);
        asteroid.xpos((Math.random()*300)+200);
        asteroid.ypos((Math.random()*5)+document.height/2);
        asteroid.xvel(0);
        asteroid.yvel(-5);
        asteroid.mass(1000);
        asteroid.xacc(0);
        asteroid.yacc(0);
    }
```

I'm trying everything to select all the 20 asteroids so i can run the methods addForce, calcNewState and resetForce but i fail miserably. Can someone please help-me with this?

Comment: Not sure to understand, but you could put all the `addCelestial` instances in an array. `var asteroids = [];` and then in the loop `asteroids.push(asteroid);`

Answer (score 0):

You want to give your custom shapes a `name` like this:

```
this.celestialBody = new Kinetic.Circle({
  name: cb.name, // <-- This works like a CSS Class and can be selected with "."
  id: cb.id,
  x:cb.x,
  y:cb.y,
  fill:cb.color,
  radius:cb.radius,
  shadowColor: cb.glow,
  shadowBlur: cb.glowBlur,
  shadowOffset: 0,
  shadowOpacity: cb.glowOpacity
});
```

In this case I would give your custom shapes a meaningful name that groups the shapes together, something like "asteroids" and add that inside your loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20;i++){

    var asteroidID = 'asteroid' + i;
    var name = 'asteroids';

    var asteroid = new addCelestial({name: name, color: 'rgb(255,255,255)',layer:layer0, id: asteroidID});
    asteroid.radius(1);
    asteroid.xpos((Math.random()*300)+200);
    asteroid.ypos((Math.random()*5)+document.height/2);
    asteroid.xvel(0);
    asteroid.yvel(-5);
    asteroid.mass(1000);
    asteroid.xacc(0);
    asteroid.yacc(0);
}
```

You can then select all asteroids by using **[container].get('.asteroids')** for example:

`var asteroids = layer.get('.asteroids')` or `var asteroids = stage.get('.asteroids')`

Returned is an array of the Kinetic objects that have the name **asteroids**.

See here for more information: https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS

**UPDATE:**

Perhaps you should try to extend the Kinetic.Shape with your custom object (celestials). Then you would have access to all of KineticJS methods along with your custom methods. Ideally this is what you would want as you don't want to lose out on the functionality of KineticJS, while using KineticJS to create objects.

See this link as a reference: [How to extend KineticJS shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892827/how-to-extend-kineticjs-shape)

Comment: The problem with that is when i try to execute the external method addForce for example. It returns: Object [object Object] has no method 'addForce' because addForce is a method off addCelestial